# Xamarin Error No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need a help about Xamarin in Visual Studio for Mac.

I installed Visual Studio for Mac since Preview version. First time I had installed it, I tried to deploy simple app to my device. I have no problem about deploying Xamarin App to my iPhone dan iPad. I forget the last time I deployed my iOS app, but I never have problem about provisioning profiles.

Today, I made an app and had successfully built. But when I want to deploy to my iPhone, I got "No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities" error.

[image]

This is what I have in Preference 
[image]

I tried to make an iOS app using Xcode and deployed to my iPhone. No problem about provisioning. I also tried open my old Xcode project, deployed it to my iPhone and still no problem.
[image]

If there is no error about provisioning in Xcode, but why there is a problem in Visual Studio for Mac?

My Visual Studio for Mac is 7.0.1 (Build 24), the latest version in Stable channel

Comment: Did you try to restart Visual Studio for Mac? It needs to be restarted in order to pick up new provisioning profiles.

Comment: Of course. It seems that there is a bug in Visual Studio